# How to write a string containing a variable to a specific cell in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write a combination of a string and a variable to a cell in VBA. All I know is that to write to a cell you would put something like:

```
("A1").Value = variable
```

If the variable was set to for example 2.

However, I would like cell A1 to display "Words 2 more words" where the variable is between strings. What is the syntax for this?

Comment: Try `("A1").Value = "Words " & variable & " more words"`

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer this method:

```
Sub MoreDynamicWay()
Dim myVariable as string
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = "word " & myVariable & " More words"
End Sub
```

or more simply if your in the active sheet already:

```
Sub MoreDynamicWay()
Dim myVariable as string
Cells(1, 1) = "word " & myVariable & " More words"
End Sub
```

or even,

```
Sub MoreDynamicWay()
Dim myVariable as string
Range("A1:z10").Cells(1, 1) = "word " & myVariable & " More words"
End Sub
```

My point in using Cells method (or .Cells method) is that it allows you more flexibly to dynamically change, modify, or position the text/value you want to paste and allows you to dynamically change or iterate through different cells more easily (the integer values in cells can be changed to variables which which you can use in iterations with loops for example)

as in the quote from this [source](http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2014/07/cells-and-range/).

*"As you know RANGE Object refers a cell or cell range with Row Number and Column Name. Cells is the most useful to use **when** you have to refer Cells/Range in a Loop then Cells is useful because both the parameters are numeric here and you can use them for loop."*

Please refer to the whole of that [page](http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2014/07/cells-and-range/) which contains an example of this.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful. Do you know how I could write to a range of cells? I'm trying to have it print "Words 1" to one cell, then "Words 2" to the cell below, and "Words n" for n cells if variable=n. I'm not sure how to create a loop for this.

Comment: No problem my pleasure! Ok Belle , I can but that's a different question so technically shouldn't be answering it here . But sure I will. If you can accept my answer above (tick on the green tick next to my answer to show it's accepted answer  ) I will send you an email on how to do that also. davidwooley78@gmail.com. there are many ways to do it.

Comment: P.s. just so you know & for future.   technically on SO one isn't supposed to ask follow up questions in your same question. What your supposed to do , in so , is write a new question for that question and post that (or look for it on Google - you'll get loads of stack results of similar questions answered in the results ). ..  but since your new to this website, i'll write you up a few short codes with explanations on how they work & links to resources ,on how to do that, if you send an email to my email .

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! I accepted your answer, I'll send you an email.

Answer (score 0):

First declare the variable preferably with a type [Read about variable types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary)

```
Dim myVariable as string
```

Then, assign the value to the variable, like this:

```
myVarible = "Words 2 more words"
```

Finally, use the variable to set the value of the Cell

```
Range("A1").Value = myVariable
```

This last line, assumes that you're going to assign the variable's value to the cell A1 in the active sheet.

The "proper" way to do it, so it doesn't relay on the active sheet is to fully qualify the reference to the range, like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("REPLACE WITH THE SHEET NAME").Range("A1").Value = myVariable
```